# Unpivot Columns with Month values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on a database that has a table containing monthly project values like so:

```
UserName | ProjectName | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Year

John     | Project1    | 1.1 | 2.1 | 1.2 | 0.8 |  1  | 2016
Alan     | Project2    | 1.6 | 3.1 | 0.2 | 5.8 | 1.2 | 2017
```

I would like to unpivot the values so the months are no longer columns and are instead a column combining month and year to make them easier to work with in reports. The ideal output would be this:

```
UserName | ProjectName | Date   | MonthValue |

John     | Project1    | 1/16   |    1.1     |
John     | Project1    | 2/16   |    2.1     |
John     | Project1    | 3/16   |    1.2     |
John     | Project1    | 4/16   |    0.8     |
John     | Project1    | 5/16   |     1      |
Alan     | Project2    | 1/17   |    1.6     |
Alan     | Project2    | 2/17   |    3.1     |
```

I'm am using SQL Server 2008 r so I should be able to use either UNPIVOT or CROSS APPLY but I can't seem to get it to work. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have tried something, it is usually helpful to post the code you have tried with any related issues or errors that occur.

Comment: And the code that you've tried so far is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `Cross Apply`

```
;with Yourtable as
(
SELECT *
FROM   ( VALUES ('John','Project1',1.1,2.1,1.2,0.8,1,2016),
                ('Alan','Project2',1.6,3.1,0.2,5.8,1.2,2017) ) tc 
                ( [UserName], [ProjectName], [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Year]) 
)
SELECT UserName,
       ProjectName,
       [Date],
       MonthValue
FROM   Yourtable
       CROSS apply (VALUES (jan, '1/' + RIGHT(year, 2)),
                           (feb, '2/' + RIGHT(year, 2)),
                           (mar, '3/' + RIGHT(year, 2)),
                           (apr, '4/' + RIGHT(year, 2)),
                           (may, '5/' + RIGHT(year, 2))) cs (MonthValue, [Date])
```

**Result :**

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╦══════╦════════════╗
║ UserName ║ ProjectName ║ Date ║ MonthValue ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬════════════╣
║ John     ║ Project1    ║ 1/16 ║ 1.1        ║
║ John     ║ Project1    ║ 2/16 ║ 2.1        ║
║ John     ║ Project1    ║ 3/16 ║ 1.2        ║
║ John     ║ Project1    ║ 4/16 ║ 0.8        ║
║ John     ║ Project1    ║ 5/16 ║ 1.0        ║
║ Alan     ║ Project2    ║ 1/17 ║ 1.6        ║
║ Alan     ║ Project2    ║ 2/17 ║ 3.1        ║
║ Alan     ║ Project2    ║ 3/17 ║ 0.2        ║
║ Alan     ║ Project2    ║ 4/17 ║ 5.8        ║
║ Alan     ║ Project2    ║ 5/17 ║ 1.2        ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╩══════╩════════════╝
```

In `MonthValue` column because of  `Numeric` values, `Integer` values will be converted to `Numeric` implicitly. Since `Numeric` has *higher* precedence than `Int`

Comment: If this answer helped you please [consider accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards the contributor and helps others to find a working solution.